# How do I fix a non-charging Yongnuo YN568II flash?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, repair, yongnuo

My Yongnuo flash suddenly refuses to charge up. The batteries are good and new (Eneloop). The charge light is dim red when I press the power button and nothing is displayed on the LCD. It never turns on. When I let go of the power button the dim red light disappears.

Can someone please help? Maybe I need to discharge it somehow or reset it but preferably without a hammer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

First thing to double-check is the batteries. How are you testing the health of the batteries?  And have you put them through enough cycles to know they're fully charged? (New is never a guarantee of good).  Are you sure they're all in the right way? Is there enough tension on the door to hold them in? ([Broken battery door tabs](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn-568ex-battery-door/) are the bane of the more recent YN models).

If it's definitely not an issue with the power supply, then chances are your flash has a bad capacitor (I'm ruling out the flash tube because of the LED faintness).  The low-low price had to come from somewhere, and with cheap flashes, there's usually an issue with copy and component consistency.  And warranty tends to be the seller replacing a bad unit (which is why you buy Yongnuos from a seller that does this). Service can be hit or miss, as it typically involves shipping to/from China.  This is why buying an "expensive" OEM unit makes sense for pros. You aren't subject to a copy lottery.

Replacing the capacitor yourself is not unheard of, but you will need knowledge of how to discharge the capacitor properly so you don't injure/kill yourself just opening up the flash, how to read the capacitance off the old one, a good source for the proper replacement part, and sufficient electronics/soldering skillz.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Yongnuo. They work until they don't. Then you replace them. Kind of like a disposable razor.